# firefox lost connection after shooting down zeitgeist

Tags: firefox, zeitgeist

What was happening in the following situation?

Firefox couldn't connect to the internet, but sudo firefox could. I had  13.10 32b on Lenovo with amd64.

The not so relevant story goes as follows:

I was playing with unetbootin
zeitgeist began crashing over and over (the usual message: oh no! a problem! do you want to report?)
I opened system monitor, there were 3 zeitgeists one ran by root other two by 'me'
I shuted down the three
firefox lost connection to internet (I noticed when trying to load other page)
firefox didn't reconnected for about 20min
then I ran sudo firefox: internet again
by then the three zeitgeist had revived but none was run by root
after restart everything was back to normal and zeitgeist didn't crashed anymore
that is the one and only time zeitgeist has crashed 
also the one and only time I was playing with unetbootin

What was that?

Comment: have you tried restarting the system?

Comment: Yes, that solved the problem.

But Im still curious why sudo firefox had internet while firefox didn't?

Answer (score 0):

When problems gets solved by "restarting the system" the cause may vary:

- A temporary or lock file problem (thanks [hbdgaf](http://chat.stackexchange.com/users/2601/hbdgaf))
- A service that didn't remove its hooks
- A dirty user session

What was it? We will never know, but only guess. The `sudo` makes Firefox running as another user that has a clean user space, like a shiny new user session. Once you restarted all problems went away.

Comment: @vasa1 [Unicorns are totally valid reasons](http://askubuntu.com/search?tab=votes&q=unicorns%20is%3aa), purple ones may be too much for the poor children D:

Comment: But see http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1teJjX-smdE